# Create pagination on an existing array

Tags: php, pagination

I have a single array of items and I want to create some paginate links. Unfortunatly I cant set the number of items to be returned in the mqin query so I always have to deal with the full array.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [key] => value
        [key] => value
    )

[1] => Array

    (
        [key] => value
        [key] => value
    )
```

Lets say I have about 100 parts to the array and I want to show 9 at a time. Im trying something like the following:

```
$pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
$i = 1; 
foreach $array as $key => $a{
 //do some html 
 $i++;  
 if($i > 9){break;}
}

$pagenumUp = $pagenum +1;
$pagenumDown = $pagenum -1;

<a href="?pagenum=<?php echo $pagenumUp; ?>">Next</a>
<a href="?pagenum=<?php echo $pagenumDown; ?>">Prev</a>
```

What im stuck on is finding a way to set the point at which the code will exiecute depending on the index. So if Im on page one then the index shoudl run from between 0 and 8. If im on page 2 it should run between 9 and 17 etc.

I thought perhaps some kind of array of numbers to check against based on the page number, but it would have to be something dynamic.

Ill leave conditionally showing the next and prev for now and figure that out later.

Comment: If array is taken from database - define items there with `LIMIT` clause

Comment: Good idea but Im not running a SQL query, Im dealing with an object already loaded in a Woocommerce template so I cant alter the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take a part (or a **slice**) or array, use `array_slice` and define it's parameters as:

```
$pageSize = 9;
$startPosition = ($_GET['pagenum'] - 1) * $pageSize;
$slice = array_slice(
    $fullArray,
    $startPosition,
    $pageSize
);
```

To split array into parts (or **chunks**) use `array_chunk`:

```
$pageSize = 9;
$chunks = array_chunk(
    $fullArray,
    $pageSize
);
// after that you can get required chunk by index - $chunks[0], $chunks[1], etc
```

Comment: Added `array_chunk` variant.